# Adding child nodes to treeView

Tags: c#, treeview, sql-server-ce

I'm currently trying to write cataloging program. For now, my goal is to make "Add" button work as I want. My code:

```
private void populatingTreeView()
{
   SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY model", con);
   SqlCeDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader();

   while (dr.Read())
   {
       TreeNode[] brandNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(dr["brand"].ToString(), false);
       if (!brandNode.Any()) 
       {
          brandNode = new TreeNode[]
          {
             treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["brand"].ToString(),dr["brand"].ToString())
          };
          platformNode[0].Nodes.Add(dr["brand"].ToString(), dr["model"].ToString());
       }
          else
          {
             platformNode[0].Nodes.Add(dr["brand"].ToString(), dr["model"].ToString());
          }
   }
}
```

It works. Almost. At the begginging my treeView looks like this

[image]

Then, after pressing "Add" button, every child node duplicates itself, except reciently added (E90 on this picture)

[image]

I sholud modify somehow my method, I get it. But after restarting the program everything is getting back to normal

[image]

My "Add" button method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO cars(model,brand) VALUES (@model,@brand)", con);
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", textBox1.Text);
  com.Parameters.Add("@brand", comboBox3.Text);

  try
     {
        int affectedRows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (affectedRows == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please, fill all the fields!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the tree before *re-adding* the nodes, which is what you are really doing:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
```